# Populating data from columns in different sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am creating an Excel sheet for budgeting. I have sheet1 with a table having columns as:

Categories: a b c d
Price: 1 2 3 4

Similarly in sheet2:

Category: e f g h
Price: 5 6 7 8

Now I have opened a sheet3 and created a table with All_Categories as one of the column headers.

What I wanted in sheet3 is, under All_Categories: a b c d e f g h

Edit: I am not able to post images since it says i need 10 points.

[check this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmbjR.jpg)

Check the above link which has 3 images. In 3rd image there is Ac column and it should contain all the data in C1 column of first image and C2 column of 2nd image

Comment: Can you just copy & paste one table under the other?

Comment: that's possible, but what I have is for each category there are expenses to a particular person. So in sheet3 I need to show the expense per person for each category.

Comment: That isn't clear at all. Please provide more details in your question, including where your data is coming from, and how you want it to be stored, as well as what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi, I am not able to post screenshot from my present browser..I will upload in 1 hour.

Comment: Hi Grade 'Eh' Bacon, I have updated with screenshots

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the cells from Sheet1 into Sheet3 and then add the cells from Sheet2 onto the end of them, you need something like this starting from Sheet3!B5 and pulled down:-

```
=IF(ROWS(B$5:B5)<=COUNTA(Sheet1!B$5:B$15),Sheet1!B5,
  IF(ROWS(B$5:B5)<=(COUNTA(Sheet1!B$5:B$15)+COUNTA(Sheet2!B$5:B$15)),
   INDEX(Sheet2!B$5:B$15,ROWS(B$5:B5)-COUNTA(Sheet1!B$5:B$15)),
   ""))
```